# Need a way combine a "word" with "character" in all possible combinations?

Tags: sql, bash

word has to be enter by user

If

```
word=pages
```

and

```
character=%
```

then first, I want the output to be

```
%pages
p%ages
pa%ges
pag%es
page%s
pages%
```

Second, substitution in word with character like this

```
%ages
p%ges
pa%es
pag%s
page%
```

Is there a way to do this using bash?
I want to use these combinations to search in SQL database.

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried?

Comment: Just using pure bash?

Comment: @123 - I'm new to linux and just know only bash and little bit of awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no particularly simple way to do this. I would suggest:

```
str=pages
wc=%
for ((i=0; i<=${#str}; i++)); do
    echo "${str:0:i}$wc${str:i}"
done
for ((i=1; i<=${#str}; i++)); do
   echo "${str:0:i-1}$wc${str:i}"
done
```

Everything is done by using parameter substring expansion, with appropriate arguments. The syntax `${str:x:y}` outputs a substring of length `y` starting at position `x`. In the first loop, `i` is the position of the character to place the `$wc` *before*. In the second loop, `i` is the position of the character to *replace*.

Comment: That's pretty simple. And definitely the best way to do it in pure bash.

Comment: By simple, I mostly meant something that would let you replace/insert characters in a string without having to expand a prefix and suffix separately. For example, `${str/#?/$wc}` and `${str/%?/$wc}` would take care of replacing the first and last letter, respectively, with a single expansion; `${str/#/$wc}` and `${str/%/$wc}` prepend/append the character to the string. Nothing short exists for the same operation at an arbitrary position inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just a variation on chepner's answer:

- The first cut is done with `printf`itself.
- The value of j is calculated inside the loop itself.

---

```
str=pages
wc=%

for ((i=0; i<=${#str}; i++)); do
    printf "%.${i}s%s%s\n" "${str}" "$wc" "${str:i}"
done

for ((i=0,j=1; i<${#str}; i++,j=i+1)); do
    printf "%.${i}s%s%s\n" "${str}" "$wc" "${str:j}"
done
```

Comment: In your second loop you don't need to have the two variables `i` and `j`. With only `i`: `printf "%.*s%s%s\n" "$i" "${str}" "$wc" "${str:i+1}"` and with only `j`: `printf "%.*s%s%s\n" "$((j-1))" "${str}" "$wc" "${str:j}"`.

Comment: That was exactly my intent. To show a different way to solve indexes. I even said so in the bulleted list: "The value of j is calculated inside the loop itself.". But yes, the math could be carried out in the executed code. It is a matter of personal preference (I think).